# ROS package for Ibeo Lux?

Tags: lidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to integrate an Ibeo Lux LIDAR, but I can not find a ROS package that handles this sensor. Does anybody know whether there is a ready-to-use ROS package available, or anything that is (close to being) compatible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225242/ros-package-for-ibeo-lux?/) by [ps4321](https://answers.ros.org/users/5779/ps4321/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-01-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danzda](https://answers.ros.org/users/28455/danzda/) on 2016-11-06**:
I am also try to get this LiDAR working with ROS, any luck with the sick_ldmrs package?

**Comment by [Hatze](https://answers.ros.org/users/29237/hatze/) on 2017-02-02**:
hi @danzda do you have any news or luck with the sick_ldmrs package?

**Comment by [danzda](https://answers.ros.org/users/28455/danzda/) on 2017-02-09**:
No, I managed to get it working on my pc but wouldn't connect to the LiDAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Sick LD-MRS is a re-badged Ibeo Lux, so the [sick_ldmrs](http://wiki.ros.org/sick_ldmrs) package might be able to talk to a Lux. Looks like it hasn't been touched since Electric, but might still be useful to you.

---

Originally posted by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) with karma: 567 on 2016-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0